# How to fix 'Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.12.0' error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, chatbot, miniconda, rasa

I am trying to create a chatbot using RASA framework . I am running the following command to install the requirements.txt file and its throwing error.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.12.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.12.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
```

Comment: Which platform is this on? Your tags mention Miniconda, but that, or its version, is not reflected in the post itself. Have you attempted to install _any_ Tensorflow version?

Answer (score 1):

That version of tensorflow is not available. Please update your requirements.txt to update from tensorflow==1.12.0 to any of below:

```
1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1, 2.0.0rc0
```